# Make a Div vertically fill its parent

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get 2 divs to appear side by side in their parent and to both vertically fill the parent. I've tried setting height and min-height to 100% but I don't understand why its not working.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="calc-wrap clear">
  <h2>Title</h2>
   <div class="calc-content clear">
    <div class="calc-form">
      <form id="cost_calculator">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>
            <h3>Find out how much your stuff costs you</h3>
          </legend>
          <ol>
            <li class="one">
              <label for="cost_of_pack">quantity</label>
              <span class="pound-label">£</span>
              <input type="number" id="cost_of_pack" name="cost_of_pack" value="0.0" min="0" step="0.10">
            </li>
            <li class="two">
              <label for="quantity_smoked">How many per day?</label>
              <input type="number" id="quantity_smoked" name="quantity_smoked" value="0">
            </li>
          </ol>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="calc-save">
      <div class="calc-results-content clear">
        <h3>Results</h3>
        <div class="calc-results">
          <div>
            <p id="weekly_cost">£<span>0.00</span> per week</p>
            <p id="monthly_cost">£<span>0.00</span> per month</p>
            <p id="annual_cost" class="noborder">£<span>0.00</span> per year</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="calc-quitnow">
          <p>Well done</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.calc-content {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  border-color: #87B7CD;
}

.calc-form,
.calc-save {
  height:100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
}

.calc-form {
  width: 60%;
}

.calc-save {
  width: 39%;
  background-color: #87B7CD;
}

.calc-results {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}
```

And a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/captncanary/k62z1d98/)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you try div container with display:table and div content display:table-cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "the Flex powers"! ;)

```css
.calc-content {
  display: flex;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  border: 3px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  border-color: #87B7CD;
}

.calc-form,
.calc-save {

  border: 1px solid red;
  /*float: left;*/
}

.calc-form {
  width: 60%;
}

.calc-save {
  width: 39%;
  background-color: #87B7CD;
}

.calc-results {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="calc-wrap clear">
  <h2>Title</h2>

  <div class="calc-content clear">
    <div class="calc-form">
      <form id="cost_calculator">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>
            <h3>Find out how much your stuff costs you</h3>
          </legend>
          <ol>
            <li class="one">
              <label for="cost_of_pack">quantity</label>
              <span class="pound-label">£</span>
              <input type="number" id="cost_of_pack" name="cost_of_pack" value="0.0" min="0" step="0.10">
            </li>
            <li class="two">
              <label for="quantity_smoked">How many per day?</label>
              <input type="number" id="quantity_smoked" name="quantity_smoked" value="0">
            </li>
          </ol>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="calc-save">
      <div class="calc-results-content clear">
        <h3>Results</h3>
        <div class="calc-results">
          <div>
            <p id="weekly_cost">£<span>0.00</span> per week</p>
            <p id="monthly_cost">£<span>0.00</span> per month</p>
            <p id="annual_cost" class="noborder">£<span>0.00</span> per year</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="calc-quitnow">
          <p>Well done</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the parent `<div>` has no defined `height`, so obviously, the children elements can't fill `100%` of the parents' `height`.

Add a `height` to your parent's class `calc-content`, e.g. `height: 200px;`.

```
calc-content {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border-color: #87B7CD;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex` in your `.calc-content` rule.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do like this:

Removed `height` from `.calc-form, .calc-save` & modified `.calc-content` with
  `display: flex;`

```css
.calc-content {
  display: flex;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  border-color: #87B7CD;
}

.calc-form,
.calc-save {
  
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
}

.calc-form {
  width: 60%;
}

.calc-save {
  width: 39%;
  background-color: #87B7CD;
}

.calc-results {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="calc-wrap clear">
  <h2>Title</h2>

  <div class="calc-content clear">
    <div class="calc-form">
      <form id="cost_calculator">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>
            <h3>Find out how much your stuff costs you</h3>
          </legend>
          <ol>
            <li class="one">
              <label for="cost_of_pack">quantity</label>
              <span class="pound-label">£</span>
              <input type="number" id="cost_of_pack" name="cost_of_pack" value="0.0" min="0" step="0.10">
            </li>
            <li class="two">
              <label for="quantity_smoked">How many per day?</label>
              <input type="number" id="quantity_smoked" name="quantity_smoked" value="0">
            </li>
          </ol>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="calc-save">
      <div class="calc-results-content clear">
        <h3>Results</h3>
        <div class="calc-results">
          <div>
            <p id="weekly_cost">£<span>0.00</span> per week</p>
            <p id="monthly_cost">£<span>0.00</span> per month</p>
            <p id="annual_cost" class="noborder">£<span>0.00</span> per year</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="calc-quitnow">
          <p>Well done</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex` on `calc-content` and keep the form element inside the fieldset element like shown below. Also need for float left now.

```css
.calc-content {
  display: flex;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  border-color: #87B7CD;
}

.calc-form,
.calc-save {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.calc-form {
  width: 60%;
}

fieldset {
  width: 60%;
}

.calc-save {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #87B7CD;
}

.calc-results {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="calc-wrap clear">
  <h2>Title</h2>

  <div class="calc-content ">


    <fieldset>
      <legend>
        <h3>Find out how much your stuff costs you</h3>
      </legend>
      <form id="cost_calculator">
        <ol>
          <li class="one">
            <label for="cost_of_pack">quantity</label>
            <span class="pound-label">£</span>

            <input type="number" id="cost_of_pack" name="cost_of_pack" value="0.0" min="0" step="0.10">
          </li>
          <li class="two">
            <label for="quantity_smoked">How many per day?</label>
            <input type="number" id="quantity_smoked" name="quantity_smoked" value="0">

          </li>
        </ol>
      </form>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="calc-save">
      <div class="calc-results-content clear">
        <h3>Results</h3>
        <div class="calc-results">
          <div>
            <p id="weekly_cost">£<span>0.00</span> per week</p>
            <p id="monthly_cost">£<span>0.00</span> per month</p>
            <p id="annual_cost" class="noborder">£<span>0.00</span> per year</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="calc-quitnow">
          <p>Well done</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parentDiv {
  height: 250px;
  background: black;
  display:flex;
}

.childDiv {  
  width:50%;
  background: grey;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid black
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv">
  <div class="childDiv">
    text1
  </div>
  <div class="childDiv">
    text2
  </div>
</div>
```